# Flask 500 (internal sever error) when Ajax calls are made

Tags: python, jquery, html, ajax, flask

I am trying to run certain python functions when buttons on my HTML page are clicked. The buttons use Ajax to communicate with my flask server.

Currently when the buttons are clicked the Ajax does cause the python functions to run, and I am able to get the results that I need. However my console shows 500 (internal sever error) and I am unsure of what the issue is.

Here is one of the Ajax call

```
<!-- stop button ajax calls -->
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#stopform').on('click', function(event) {

        alert("Chamber Stopped");

        clearInterval(start_interval);
        $.ajax({
            data : {
            },
            type : 'POST',
            url : '/stop'
        })

        });
        });

</script>
```

and the python route that it calls too

```
@app.route('/stop', methods=['POST'])
def stop():
    #stops control system 
    gpio.control_stop()
```

Comment: 500 internal server error means your Python code has a bug. I don't  know what gpio is but it might be the issue. What if you change that line to a simple return True or something and see what happens. Also try running the dev server with debug=True to get more useful error messages

Comment: Also, you should wait for the server to respond before doing stuff like `clearInterval(start_interval)` because if for whatever reason the server doesn't respond positively, then your front end will be out of sync with what your server is thinking!